# how many threads to run in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I had this brilliant idea to speed up the time needed for generating 36 files: use 36 threads!! Unfortunately if I start one connection (one `j2ssh` connection object) with 36 threads/sessions, everything lags way more than if I execute each thread at a time.
Now if I try to create 36 new connections (36 `j2ssh` connection objects) then each thread has a separate connection to server, either i get out of memory exception (somehow the program still runs, and successfully ends its work, slower than the time when I execute one thread after another).

So what to do? how to find the optimal thread number I should use?
because `Thread.activeCount()` is 3 before starting mine 36 threads?! i'm using Lenovo laptop Intel core i5.

Comment: Are you running your working threads on the server or the client side of the j2ssh connection?

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann running them on the server, thread == send 2 commands to server

Comment: Sounds like you need to see if you are running out of memory in your JVM.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could narrow it down to a more reasonable number of threads with an `ExecutorService`. You probably want to use something near the number of processor cores available, e.g:

```
int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    service.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // do what you need per file here
        }
    });
}
service.shutdown();
```

Comment: Well you see here completion time is ~30 min I guess every one from 36 operations is created and executed one after another,thread1.start;thread1.end;thread2.start;thread2.end..thread36.end... I personally expect excecution atleast within 12 min not 30, it it possible to increase speed now the threads number(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
) I set is 4

Answer (score 5):

A good practice would be to spawn threads equivalent to the number of cores in your processor. I normally use a `Executors.fixedThreadPool(numOfCores)` executor service and keep feeding it the jobs from my job queue, simple. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your Intel i5 has two cores; hyperthreading makes them look like four.  So you only get four cores' worth of parallelization; the rest of your threads are time sliced.

Assume 1MB RAM per thread just for thread creation, then add the memory that each thread requires to process the file.  That will give you an idea about why you're getting out of memory errors.  How big are the files you're dealing with?  You can see that you'll have a problem if they're very large to have them in memory at the same time.

I'll assume that the server receiving the files can accept multiple connections, so there's value in trying this.

I'd benchmark with 1 thread and then increase them until I found that the performance curve was flattening out.

Comment: well you are right the serever can proceed atleast three commands at the same time(maybe even 36). So I'm thinking to run two commands on threads1,2  at the same time and then on the main thread the third command?!

Answer (score 1):

Using more threads than the number of cores on your machine is going only to slow down the whole process. It will speed up till you reach this number.

Comment: so if i have 4 cores i believe that optimal speed is using 3 threads at the time? atleast I have examined(using several commands) the time this way:Executors.fixedThreadPool(2) -time 6:40min fixedThreadPool(3)-5:28min. ThreadPool(4)-9:56 min waylonger! ThreadPool(8)-13:13 min. inconclusion max number of  threads I can use is 3 ?!

Answer (score 1):

Brute force: Profile incrementally. Increase the number of threads gradually and check the performance. As the number to connections is just 36, its should be easy

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that if you create 36 threads you still have one or two processors and it would be switching between threats most of the time.

I would say you increment the threads a little bit, let's say 6 and see the behavior. And then go from there

Answer (score 1):

One way to tune the numebr of threads to the size of the machine is to use

```
int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
int threads = processors * N; // N could 1, 2 or more depending on what you are doing.
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
```

Answer (score 1):

First **you have to find out where the bottle neck is**.

- If it is the SSH connection, it usually does not help to open multiple connections in parallel. Better use multiple channels on one connection, if needed.
- If it is the disk IO, creating multiple threads writing (or reading) only helps if they are accessing different disks (which is seldom the case).  But you could have another thread doing CPU-bound things while you are waiting on your disk IO in one thread.
- If it is the CPU, and you have enough idle cores, more threads can help. Even more, if they don't need to access common data.  But still, more threads than cores (+ some threads doing IO) does not help. (Also take in mind that usually there are other processes on your server, too.)

Comment: another note: on unix-ish machines, htop is a good tool to see CPU and memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you don't create more threads than you have processing units or you are likely to create more overhead with context switching than you gain in concurrency. Also remember that you only have 1 HDD and 1 HDD controller as a result, I doubt multithreading is going to help you at all here.

Comment: **remember that you only have 1 HDD and 1 HDD controller as a result, I doubt multithreading is going to help you at all here.** why? if i can open through putty 5 different windows(5 connections to server ) and excecute 5command groups, i should be able to do the same thing using java ?!

Comment: It wasn't clear if you were creating the 36 files on one system or not, if you are making 36 connections to a single system then drive concurrency could be a problem unless the system is operating a storage system beyond a single HDD. You have to imagine that an HDD is a single threaded entity, you can only do one write at a time.

Comment: You need to understand that switching between threads is not 'free', it costs time. It's only a little time but when you multiple that time by 36 threads which are probably switching contexts many times per second and that the library probably isn't heavily optimised for multithreading, you are looking at way more time than you might imagine. Threading isn't a universal panacea and unless you really understand what's going on I'd suggest don't use it, it's like a really sharp knife. If you don't know how to use it properly then you are going to hurt yourself.